# How to get only tables, not views using SHOW TABLES?

Tags: mysql

`SHOW TABLES` gives you tables+views.

How do I retrieve only tables?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
show full tables where Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

verbatim.

Or put another way;

```
show full tables where Table_Type != 'VIEW'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

The link at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-tables.html
tells us that we cannot use LIKE and WHERE together ( for  mysql 5.5.x - 8.x  ).

So this statement WILL throw errors ( show tables which are NOT views and are further filtered by %name% );

```
  show full tables like "%sometablename%"  where Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE';
```

U will have to choose either LIKE   or  WHERE in one statement , not both simultaneously.

::: Solution ( requires you know the database name ( say dbName)  ) :::

```
   show full tables where  Tables_in_dbName like "%main%" 
   and  Table_type = "Base Table";
```