# Spark - get tables from database

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to perform an operation on all the tables from given databases(s) and so I am using following code.

However, it gives me views as well, is there a way I can filter only tables?

**code**

```scala
  def getTables(databaseName: String)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Array[String] = {
    val tables = spark.sql(s"show tables from ${databaseName}").collect().map(_(1).asInstanceOf[String])
    logger.debug(s"${tables.mkString(",")} found")
    tables
  }
```

also, `show views shows error"

```scala
scala> spark.sql("show views from gshah03;").show
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
missing 'FUNCTIONS' at 'from'(line 1, pos 11)

== SQL ==
show views from gshah03;
-----------^^^

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:241)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:643)
  ... 49 elided
```

Comment: Perhaps [How to get only tables, not views using SHOW TABLES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908680/how-to-get-only-tables-not-views-using-show-tables)

Comment: @LuckyGuess thanks but it's not working for `hive` the column `table type` does not exist

Comment: well...maybe you can do `show views` and except with `show tables`?

Comment: @LuckyGuess it shows error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```scala
  val df = spark.range(1, 5)
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_view")
    println(spark.catalog.currentDatabase)
    val db: Database = spark.catalog.getDatabase(spark.catalog.currentDatabase)
    val tables: Dataset[Table] = spark.catalog.listTables(db.name)
    tables.show(false)

    /**
      * default
      * +-------+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
      * |name   |database|description|tableType|isTemporary|
      * +-------+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
      * |df_view|null    |null       |TEMPORARY|true       |
      * +-------+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
      */
```

Comment: what are you trying so show here,  output shows the `view` name.

Comment: you can filter out  the views using table Type, no?